# Solr search, number of results

Tags: theming, search

I'm trying to find a way to display the number of resuts in a solr search.
I need to display it in search-results template.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Theres a good article on Lullabot about this http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/display-count-search-results-drupal-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link given is a nice one to deal with the default search result number count. In Apache Solr you can use the following code to get the total number of documents returned in the search result.

```
if (apachesolr_has_searched() && ($response = apachesolr_static_response_cache())) {
  $returned_doc_num = $response->response->numFound;
}
```

Comment: Actually I only used $GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0] as I have a pagination system.

Comment: That is fine I hope, but never used it. But you can use the numFound in templates as well.
Check https://www.drupal.org/node/1516462 comment #4, #6 & #8